# Best way to create a table with each possible combination of product options and variations

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to implement in PostgreSQL a table for each combination of option and variation.

This is my existing tables:

[image]

Imagine this scenario:

Product: T-Shirt

Options: Size, Color

Variations: Size:Small,Medium,Large | Color:White,Black,Yellow

I need to have a row for each combination to control quantity and price seperately.

So i need a row with Size:Small,Color:White, one with  Size:Small,Color:Black etc...

It isn't necessary to execute all in SQL, i manipulate the data in program logic in Go.

I thought about making a table with:

id |price | quantity | option1_id | option2_id | option3_id

and compare the values that i get from my form and get the appropriate price and qty.However i do not know how to guarantee that the options on my form are displayed on the correct order as to not put the option id on my query.

Is there better option?Perhaps saving the combination in JSON on one column and loading in a array in JS and manipulating it there?

To explain it a bit better(hopefully):

I display on my site some select inputs with the options and variations that i have inserted,like this.[image]
Where each option on the dropdown menu has a value of variation_id and the name of the menu is the option_id,ex. 120:1400 where 120 is the option_id and 1400 is the variant attached to it and currently selected.So when user adds product to cart it sends this JSON to server`[{"option_id":3,"variant_id":13},{"option_id":433,"variant_id":1085}]`

I know how to make a table with each possible combination, but i don't know how to link the variants selected to the one row on my table.

I want to implement the same way that Woocommerce does it.

This is the Attributes(Options)

[image]

And those are the Variations that are generated

[image]

As you can see there's an entry for each possible configuration.

Currently i have set up the Name and Values of the third image. product_option  has the name of the option and there are multiple product_variation rows pointed to the option_id, each with a variation name like Small,Medium etc...

I don't know how to create a new table like the 4th image.

Comment: `SELECT ... JOIN ... INTO` should do it, right? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-selectinto.html

Comment: Alex can you elaborate what you mean by *"how to guarantee that the options on my form are displayed on the correct order as to not put the option id on my query."* What form? And what is the correct order? And what query? Maybe, if possible, show the expected input and the desired output.

Comment: Hi @mkopriva, i sure can.I updated my OP.Forget what i said about the form, you will be confused for no reason.Check the update and tell me if you don't understand.Thanks

Comment: I must admit that I don't understand what you are asking. Are you asking whether this is a good data model? I see from your tables that there are no general options like 'Size' and 'Color', but every product has its own options. Thus one product can have 'Size (width)', 'Size (length)' and 'Color', another 'Length', 'Width' and 'Main Color'. Same for the variations ('30"', '30 inch', '30inch', '30'). Users searching for products by attributes may get a tad disappointed. Does that already answer your question?

Comment: Or are you asking what to store with an order with the data model given? Answer: You'd store the variation_id, because this is linked to exactly one option, which again is linked to exactly one product. And if you are asking where to store a product variation price: in the product_variation table. For the same reason.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner,each product can have no options or multiple options,there are no general options.So each option is added to the DB even if some products share the same option name.I have updated my OP again hopefully with more details and an example of what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Ah, I see. (Or at least I think so.) This is not about some site for a customer (although you mention a user adding a product to a cart), but about a site for a shop owner who wants to enter new products into the system? I'd make this two steps then: (1) a combination button building and showing all variants, so prices can then be entered, (2) a save button to store the data in the database. For the latter the idea to just send a Json string with all the data to a function that does the inserts seems appropriate.

Comment: Well actually it's an ecommerce platform SaaS, so as you said, a shop owner will be able to add products and define variations as well.What you describe seems to be the front end process which i have already created. I am looking for tips on the database schema for the combinations of options and attributes(variations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way.It's called Cartesian Product.

Here is how it's done.

This is a function that i found online,from this repo https://github.com/schwarmco/go-cartesian-product

```
func Iter(params ...[]interface{}) chan []interface{} {
    // create channel
    c := make(chan []interface{})
    // create waitgroup
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    // call iterator
    wg.Add(1)
    iterate(&wg, c, []interface{}{}, params...)
    // call channel-closing go-func
    go func() { wg.Wait(); close(c) }()
    // return channel
    return c
}

// private, recursive Iteration-Function
func iterate(wg *sync.WaitGroup, channel chan []interface{}, result []interface{}, params ...[]interface{}) {
    // dec WaitGroup when finished
    defer wg.Done()
    // no more params left?
    if len(params) == 0 {
        // send result to channel
        channel <- result
        return
    }
    // shift first param
    p, params := params[0], params[1:]
    // iterate over it
    for i := 0; i < len(p); i++ {
        // inc WaitGroup
        wg.Add(1)
        // create copy of result
        resultCopy := append([]interface{}{}, result...)
        // call self with remaining params
        go iterate(wg, channel, append(resultCopy, p[i]), params...)
    }
}
```

Here's how you can use it

```
a := []interface{}{"Small", "Medium", "Large"}

b := []interface{}{"White", "Black", "Yellow"}

var d [][]interface{}
d = append(d,a)
d = append(d,b)
c := Iter(d...)

for product := range c {
    fmt.Println(product)
}
```

I then store each product as a JSON string to the database